# OCI: How to create a boot volume from an existing volume's using the oci sdk

Tags: python, oracle, sdk, oracle-call-interface

I want to use the OCI python sdk to create a boot volume.

So i have the id from the source compute instance's boot volume ID.

Below i try to do it using BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails(). If i was passing in the id this would give me the error in python.

> "init takes 1 argument but you passed 2"

Here is my code

```py
    def create_boot_volume_and_wait_for_state(source_boot_volume_id,
                                              compartment_id,
                                              source='boot_volume_details',
                                              wait_for_states=BootVolume.LIFECYCLE_STATE_AVAILABLE,
                                              operation_kwargs=None, waiter_kwargs=None,
                                              **model_kwargs):

        source_details = BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails()
        availability_domain = ComputeRestUtils.get_first_availability_domain(compartment_id)

        create_boot_volume_details = CreateBootVolumeDetails(
            availability_domain=availability_domain.name,
            display_name="test",
            compartment_id=compartment_id,
            source_details=source_details,
            **model_kwargs)
```

How do i link it to the instance's boot volume?

Answer (score 0):

`BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails` requires two arguments type and source id something as below.

```
 source_details=oci.core.models.BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails(
        type="bootVolume",
        id="ocid1.bootvolume.oc1.iad.<MASKED>")))
```

You may find a complete sample at https://github.com/oracle-devrel/oci-sdk-python-samples/tree/main/samples/create-boot-volume

You may also refer to OCI SDK documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.79.0/api/core/models/oci.core.models.BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails.html#oci.core.models.BootVolumeSourceFromBootVolumeDetails